# How can I scale an element to fit its parent?

Tags: html, css, scale

I want to know if it's possible to scale an element (not an image) to fit its `div` parent. `transform: scale();` and `transform-origin: n n n;` are useful for what I want to do, however, I can't seem to adjust scale to fit the container (tried using percentage values), so the element will always be at a fixed size.

The element itself is a `<table>` element with various elements inside. I want to scale everything to fit the parent `<div>` width. This is generated by an external script that I do not have access to, thus I can't access the element until the page is fully loaded.

I tried using `transform: scale();` and `transform-origin: n n n;` but this allows me to scale to a fixed value, and the resulting element will get cut off on smaller screen resolutions.

I would be grateful for any solution or alternatives.

Comment: When you say you want it to scale with the element you mean you want everything (text, images) to grow and shrink proportionately?

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] of what you have so far? Hopefully that will better illustrate your problem.

Comment: @88MPG It's a table with img elements inside. I want to resize everything. (this is generated by an external script so I cant access the element until the page is loaded.)

Comment: @TylerH I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough. I thought it was understandable.

Comment: If it's just a table with `<img>` elements inside can you use `object-fit: cover`?

Comment: so `width: 100%`  is not what you want ?

Comment: Have you already tryed `inheritance`? Please, provide an example.